Identify two figures for similarity
I am trying to find a reliable way to determine the similarity between geometric shapes (polygons).
In one of my approaches, I tried to use the cvopen library and the findContours() and matchShapes() methods. However, this is not an ideal way for me, since I can have very similar shapes, but with different point coordinates. And accordingly, two shapes are determined to be completely different. An example is below

I started to explore the issue further, and tried to determine the identity of figures based on the area, perimeter, and comparison of the angles of the figures. But this option is also not entirely optimal, since similar figures can differ in size (and therefore in area and perimeter), and the angles of the figures can be slightly different. An example is below

You may ask: which figures do I consider similar, and which figures are different? In the example below, the figures are categorically not similar to each other, but the first two photos, I will classify as similar figures

I am not asking for a ready-made code for the solution, I am only asking for advice and ideas from you. What other methods can I try to correctly determine the similarity of figures?

Are figures considered similar if they have exactly the same shape but one is many times larger/smaller? What about where one is a rotation of the other?

matchShapes should work.  Why do you find that it does not?  Scale and rotation should not be the issue.

See https://learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77774217/12728244

Are you able to define what similarity exactly means here?  Typical approaches are contour moments, hausdorff distance, chamfer distance and such things, but often this doesn't fit one's intuitive implicit definition of "similarity" good enough. Approaches can be used with or without normalizing position, size and angle of the shapes.

@MarkSetchell Yes, in this case the figures are also considered similar

we might be able to help you if you could just reveal where these figures come from. you have some application in mind, but you have kept that a secret so far. you're being abstract/vague. that obscures the true task.

@ChristophRackwitz I didn't think it was important. I can share: I compare the text in the document for identity by key phrases. I made a template of the figure, defining the coordinates of the key phrases. On each subsequent incoming document, I search for key phrases and draw a figure. Then I compare the figure on the template with the new figure

do you care purely about the text, or also the document/layout of the text? in what ways can the text itself differ? which differences are irrelevant, which are significant? -- sounds like a NLP task, perhaps ML/DL/AI. I would not have thought to approach that "graphically".

One option is to use shape-similarity (a few modules) that uses mainly the Fréchet distance :
from shapesimilarity import shape_similarity

def are_similar(p1, p2, threshold=0.9): #  << adjust if needed
    try:
        sim = shape_similarity(p1, p2)
    except AssertionError:
        sim = 0
    return sim > threshold


Used inputs :




yellow
red




case1
[[101, 0], [548, 4], [430, 216], [400, 211], [330, 313], [240, 324], [219, 245], [101, 0]]
[[115, 12], [554, 10], [445, 219], [417, 212], [353, 317], [267, 330], [242, 254], [115, 12]]


case2
[[104, 0], [534, 3], [421, 198], [390, 194], [321, 290], [236, 298], [217, 233], [104, 0]]
[[158, 32], [554, 30], [430, 195], [413, 199], [328, 306], [233, 321], [251, 240], [158, 32]]


case3
[[168, 0], [555, 1], [452, 212], [427, 209], [365, 309], [287, 319], [271, 247], [168, 0]]
[[102, 232], [549, 190], [378, 255], [408, 298], [295, 334], [102, 232]]




Thank you for paying attention to my question and sharing the code. I will look into this approach and get back to you.

Thank you, your approach really helped me

An interesting question and I am sure it can be looked at from many points, since so many questions are left open. My question for you: Do you want to be able to tell if they are similar in shape? or position too?
A couple of methods from the top of my head right now:

if different positions of the shapes are a problem, you can always move them over each other before proceeding with an analysis, or if more sophisticated solution is needed you could try different positions, scales and even rotations of one of the polygons and at each position you could do one of the analyses below
try iterating over the endpoints of the polygons and checking their coordinates, recording the distance between an endpoint of polygon 1 and polygon 2, then calculating mean distance (or median, or maximum) as a measure of similarity (assumption: polygons with the same number of endpoints)
seeing how big the intersection area is, big area = higher similarity (careful, this does not always hold - two shapes can have the same area without being similar in shape, but in your provided images it might work)
probably a heavy overkill, but training a neural net to calculate the similarity score of two images could help

Good luck!


If the figures are the same but different sizes - for me they should be identical;
If the figures are the same but lie in different coordinates - for me they should be identical;
If 1-3 corners have different slopes (as in example number two), but in general it is clear that the figures are similar - for me they should be identical;

